# How can I attach to released in the testflight application to debug?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I have XCode, Device with the application installed via testflight, Release IPA, dSym.
Simple `attach to process` fails.

> error: attach by pid '66475' failed -- unable to attach

I want to debug using IDE. Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this.  For the debugger to be able to attach to a process, the app binary needs to be signed with a special entitlement (get-task-allow).  Otherwise the OS will deny the debugger's ability to attach - as you have seen.  The Store doesn't allow you to submit apps that have this entitlement, so you can't debug released versions of your app.  OTOH, nor can anyone else, which many folks view to be a good thing...

You can make a "DebugRelease" Configuration that uses the same settings as your release build but adds this entitlement by hand if you need to debug the code that comes from the Release build - in case you have bugs that only show up in the fully optimized build, for instance.  You just can't debug the Store version.

Comment: I faced an issue which is reproduced only using release IPA file. Switching debug/release mode while usual debug process doesn't reproduce such bug. Nonetheless, thanks

Comment: Do you have any proof?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, proof of what?

Comment: is there any documentation about where explains such behavior?

Comment: get-task-allow is described in this TechNote: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2415/_index.html.  It doesn't add much more detail, however.  Searching for get-task-allow here will find some other bits of information, and there are a few ADC Forum threads where this is discussed.  I'm not sure there is other more formal documentation of how this works.